# Sum of all degrees in a connect planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

All of the faces in a connected planar graph (including the outer infinite region) are either hexagons, heptagons or octagons and all of the vertices are of the third degree.

Let x be the number of pentagons, y the number of heptagons and z the number of octagons. Here I have the formula D = 5x + 6y + 7z, where D is the sum of all the degrees in the graph. I know that D/2 and D/3 are respectively the number of edges and the number of vertices in the graph (which I need in order to solve a task which involves this specific graph), but I cannot understand how I get to this formula (how I derive D).

Could someone offer an explanation as to why D is the sum of all the degrees in the graph? I have a feeling that I'm too stupid to visualize it in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5x+6y+7z$ is the number of *corners of faces* in the planar graph. Each corner of a face is at a particular vertex, and at each vertex there are as many corners of faces as its degree.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are $5x+6y+7z$ sides for all the hexagons, heptagons or octagons, but we have counted each edge twice here! However, the sum $D$ of all the degrees of all the vertices also counts each edge twice (we count one for each 'end' of each edge). Thus, $D=5x+6y+7z.$